# hashWithIndifferentAccess is preventing update of a single hash value from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash, sql-update

Currently I am trying to update a value of a single key, "elementOne", in a hash I call :section_text

the hash looks like this:

```
section_text => {"elementOne" => "words", "elementTwo" => "other words"}
```

here is my model:

```
 class DynamicElement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dynamic_page_elements
  has_many :dynamic_pages, :through => :dynamic_page_elements
  store :section_text, accessors: [ :elementOne, :elementTwo ]
 end
```

my form text area:

```
 <%= form.text_area :elementOne, value: dynamic_element.section_text["elementOne"] %>
   <div class="actions">
 <%= form.submit %>
```

strong params

```
  def dynamic_element_params
    params.require(:dynamic_element).permit(:style, :description, :section_text, :elementOne)
  end
```

When I run the update (from "Birthday Gifts!!!" to "Birthday Gifts!!!?") the params show exactly what i'm expecting, and when the SQL code starts to run it even starts to replace the exact key value pair in question.

BUT, as you can see "--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess" has been appended to key which is preventing the update from moving forward, not to mention its not the format I originally was going for.

******** TERMINAL PIC BELOW*********

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQeGO.png)

How can I prevent this so I can save the new value as is? 
I did some reading that and from what I've found it sounds like rails is serializing this through the default serializer, YAML?

A little lost at this point, any help is greatly appreciated!
(using postgresql)

*EDIT* 
Am I even going down the best path here to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is probably:

```
elem = DynamicElement.joins(:dynamic_page_elements).find_by!(
  dynamic_page_elements: params.slice(:dynamic_page_id),
  description: "SectionOne",
)
new_section_text = elem.section_text.merge(dynamic_element_params)
elem.update(section_text: new_section_text)
```

Some tips:

- make use of db joins to avoid `nil`s -- they're a common source of bugs and causes your code to be ["timid"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8J0j2xJFgQ)
- avoid mutating (`merge!`) by default, keeps changes discrete and easier to track
- use good naming to keep track of the concepts you're handling

  - e.g. not clear what `element.update(derp)` was doing

Comment: thanks for answering, I actually had to simply change

     store :section_text, accessors: [ :elementOne, :elementTwo ]



to


      store_accessor :section_text, :elementOne, :elementTwo